# Doubt in proof of theorem proving analyticity of $\Delta(\tau) $ in H.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-functions

While studying Number theory from Apostol's Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory I have a doubt in proof of theorem 1.15 .

It's image is ->[image]

> I have doubt in line 11 when Apostol says that he will invoke lemma 1 .  But the series in lemma 1 converges absolutely iff $\alpha$>2 . 
>   Then why he proves for $\alpha$ =2 ?

Adding image of Lemma 2 - 
[image]

Can someone please explain.

Comment: There's no mention of $\alpha=2$ in Apostol's text.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown in image 1 , he proves after (6) for $\alpha$ =2  where he writes to prove (6) it suffices to prove...

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, then how it is sufficient to prove $|m + n\tau| ^2 > K | m+ ni|^2 $ . How lemma 1 would be invoked if power =2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the inequality after (6) to the power $-\alpha/2$, then you get (6) with $M=K^{-\alpha/2}$.